# Can I find who the corresponding author of a paper is, and their email address, with pybliometrics?

Tags: pybliometrics

I am trying to identify the corresponding author of a paper, and their email address, using pybliometrics. Is this possible? AbstractRetrieval allows me to get a list of author IDs, but I am not sure if I can identify who the corresponding author is.

Downloading a set of results on Scopus.com allows me to grab the correspondance address (which has the email) so I am curious if the API and/or pybliometrics has similar functionality.

I've tried the AbstractRetrieval class, but can't seem to find an attribute for corresponding author info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

Via the API, you can find out who's the corresponding author but but their email address with `AbstractRetrieval(). correspondence`:

> List of namedtuples representing the authors to whom correspondence should be addressed, in the form (surname, initials, organization, country, city_group). Multiple organziations are joined on semicolon.

(From https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/AbstractRetrieval.html#pybliometrics.scopus.AbstractRetrieval.correspondence)

Via scopus.com you can also retrieve the email address. Alas, they do but provide this via the API.

In any case, the share of missing correspondence information increases in publication age of the document.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. It is unfortunate the emails aren't available via the API, but thanks for confirming.